# Offline APT mirror with Ubuntu updates - how can I build them?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, apt, offline-files, apt-mirror

I'm looking for a way to create a mirror of the Official ubuntu apt archive for jammy (22.04) / AMD64.

The mirror should contain updates for all packages that go into a standard Ubuntu server provisioned with cloud-init along with some selected extra packages and their transitive dependencies.

I have been playing around with a tool called aptly, but I'm having problems coming up with a managable way to express these requirements. I'm not sure what the "root" packages in Ubuntu Server are or if aptly is able to reliably resolve their transitive dependencies.

When I do apt upgrade, I notice that sometimes packages such as kernels don't just get updates, but change name.

Anyone pointers on how to approach this problem are appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: why do you want to mirror something that you actually not using? apt-cacher-ng keeps the footprint small and the environment. you can Archiv this Also with a squid proxy if it's already been deployed